# Using ajax and checkboxes for dynamic search of database records

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, checkbox

I have a database of events and I want users to be able to filter the events in real time via groupings of checkboxes - state, month, etc. I've given checkboxes within the same group the same name: `name="state"` for all state checkboxes, `name="month"` for all month checkboxes, etc.

I have a function that fires whenever any checkbox on the page is clicked and tried three methods to output the selected values:

**Method 1**

```
var state = $('input[name="state"]:checked').map(function() {
        return "'"+$(this).val()+"'";
    }).get().join(",");
var month = $('input[name="month"]:checked').map(function() {
        return "'"+$(this).val()+"'";
    }).get().join(",")
```

Example console.log when making selections on the page looks like

```
'Alaska','Arkansas','California' 'January','February','March'
```

**Method 2**

```
var formData = $('#form').serialize();
```

Example console.log when making selections on the page looks like

```
state=Alaska&state=Arkansas&state=California&month=January&month=February&month=March
```

**Method 3**

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(formData);
```

Example console.log when making selections on the page looks like

```
"state=Alaska&state=Arkansas&state=California&month=January&month=February&month=March"
```

I've tried both `GET` and `POST` types for the ajax. I think POST is what I'm after; that allows me to send the JSON.stringify to my individual PHP variables, run `$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));` to decode the string and when I `echo "$data";` back to my HTML page I get a dynamic list of checkbox values as I check/uncheck them:

```
state=Alaska&state=Arkansas&state=California&month=January&month=February&month=March
```

I need help in finding how to take the values of the selected checkboxes and query my database to return any record that matches the currently checked checkboxes. I've tried

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM events WHERE state = '".$state."' OR month = '".$month."'";
```

and

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM events WHERE month REGEXP 'January|February|March|...'"
```

and

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM events WHERE (state = 'Alabama' OR state = 'Alaska' OR...) OR (month = 'January' OR month = 'February' OR...)";
```

I feel like it's just my lack of php-fu and you all can enlighten me on a simple solution that I've been ignorantly overlooking. I'm also open to the possibility that I'm approaching this the wrong way. I'd like to know how to do this the best way. My PHP knowledge is clearly lacking so please use small words.

--**edit 1**--
The checkboxes follow this pattern:

```
<li class="filter-item">
 <label class="checkbox" for="January">
  <input type="checkbox" class="month" id="January" value="January" name="month"> January
 </label>
</li>
<li class="filter-item">
 <label class="checkbox" for="February">
  <input type="checkbox" class="month" id="February" value="February" name="month"> February
 </label>
</li>
...
```

--**edit 2**--
I've tried the following PHP and get no results; echo doesn't even push out selected values.

```
$state_values = $_POST['state']; 
$month_values = $_POST['month']; 

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','****','****','db');
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$state_values = array_map(function($val) use ($con){
    return $con->real_escape_string($val);
});
$states = implode('|', $state_values);

$month_values = array_map(function($val) use ($con){
    return $con->real_escape_string($val);
});
$months = implode('|', $month_values);


mysqli_select_db($con,"events");

$sql="SELECT * FROM events WHERE state REGEXP '$states'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "$state_values";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<div class="panel panel-default">';
echo '<div class="panel-heading">';
echo '<span class="lead">' . $row['name'] . '</span><br>';
echo '<span class="small">' . $row['description'] . '</span>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="panel-body">';
echo '<div class="row">';
echo '<div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">';
echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>'  . $row['month'] .' ' . $row['day'] . ', ' . $row['year'] . '</div>';
echo '<div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">';
echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>'  . $row['city'] . ', ' . $row['state'] . '</div>';
echo '<div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">';
echo '<a href="' . $row['url'] . '" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" target="_blank">Visit Race Site</a></div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: do you have them form markup?

Answer (score 0):

Something you can do for submitting forms to php, when you have a multi valued form variable like a group of checkboxes, you can name them `name[]` and `month[]` instead of `name` and `month`. I see you are using jQuery, so instead of map, you can use jQuery's [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

```
var data=$('#yourForm').serialize();
```

would return something like

```
state[]=Alaska&state[]=Arkansas&state[]=California&month[]=January&month[]=February&month[]=March
```

You can pass that to your php script over ajax, then when they are getting sent to `$_POST` php will interpret them as [array push syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php), so `$_POST['state']` and `$_POST['month']` will be arrays instead of strings. Then [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$stateList=implode("','",$_POST['state']); //'Alaska','Arkansas','California'
$monthList=implode("','",$_POST['month']); //'January','February','March'
```

and then the sql would be

```
$query='SELECT * FROM events WHERE state IN ('.$stateList.') OR month IN ('.$monthList.')';
```

So I don't think this situation necessarily calls for any regex. `imploding` checkbox values from a form to shove into a sql `IN` clause is something that I find myself doing all of the time.